# How to specify localhost for SSIS package source server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I have a job running on SQL Server 2012, where one of the steps is of type "SQL Server Integration Services Package". For the "Package source" I choose SSIS Catalog. For the "Server", if I type in the name of the server, everything works fine, but if I type in localhost I get an error.

How do I specify that the SSIS Catalog that I want to use is under the same server where the job is running?

Comment: and the error message is...

Comment: Just the standard can't find host, etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the local server with a period `.`

If you have an instance name, too, then use `.\instancename`